# How to copy data starting from end of the array in C/C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a function `void copy(char *temp,char input[length])`. What I need to do is copy the values of temp into input array but starting from the end of the input array.

I did not frame the question correctly.
Here's what I'm trying to do.

I've input array of length 20. I get a temp array with values 'test'. Then I would like to copy temp in the input array where input[19]=t,input[18]=e etc.

Now when I call the function again, and if I want to copy xyz to input array, then input[15]=x,input[14]=y,input[13]=z.

I want to do this till I fill the input array with all the values.

```
void copy(char *temp,char input[])
```

This is the function definition.

Now let's look at what we have to do,

```
char* temp={"abcde"};
char input[100]={};
//I want to move data from temp into input array such that
printf("%c",input[95]); // gives output as a
printf("%c",input[96]); // gives output as b
```

This is what I've written so far.

```
char* copy(char* ptr,char data[])
{
int start=sizeof(data)/sizeof(char)-strlen(data);
int end=start-strlen(ptr);
int j=0;
int counter=0;

for(counter=start;counter>end;counter--)
{
    data[counter]=ptr[j++];   
}        
printf("%s",data);
return data;


}
```

When I call this function I get another error in this manner,

```
char data[100]={};
char* temp={"abcde"};
char* output=copy(temp,data);
data=output;
```

incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [100]’ for data=output line

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) In particular, you need an extra parameter so that you know what the length of the array is. Or if the array holds a NULL terminated string, you can use strlen() to get the length of the c-string.

Comment: Nah it's not homework. I'm trying with storing a temp variable starting from end of the array and copy data till length of the temp array

Comment: By _starting from the end_ do you mean to say that the content of `temp` is __reversed__ in `input`?

Comment: Define a proper interface of the function, and then add a use case (code) with the inputs and outputs.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Made more changes hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

That is already implemented as an algorithm:

```
std::reverse_copy( input, input+length, output );
```

In a related note, the signature of your function:

```
void copy(char *temp,char input[length])
```

actually means:

```
void copy(char *temp,char *input)
```

That is, the length of the `input` array is not part of the signature of the function, and it will not be checked by the compiler. Consider passing the size as an extra argument or else passing the array by reference. Additionally the source array is not modified, so it should be a `const char*`

Comment: Explained what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a string, you can use `strlen` to check the size of the input string and then copy it reversed. On the other hand if it is an array of chars, which doesn't end with `'\0'`, you have to take a new parameter for the length.

First case (you said `copy the values of temp into input array`, so we're copying the content of `temp` into `input`, dismissing its name):

```
void copy(char *temp, char input[length])
{
    for(int i = strlen(temp) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        input[i] = temp[i];
    }
}
```

Second case:

```
void copy(char *temp, char *input, size_t length)
{
    for(int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        input[i] = temp[i];
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can use the standard library function [`reverse_copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse_copy/).

Comment: I would assume that *input* is the source of the data, and *temp* the destination. If for no other reason just because it is called *input*.

Comment: Yep, that's what I think, but I just did what he wrote. Anyways, he'd just have to change the name again...